# Tool to view GPOs in a readable way?

Tags: active-directory

I received a GPO report in HTML. Maybe that's the first problem, since, according to my research, XML is a much better option. Anyway, I tried converting it to XML, but there are always issues so the tools that might exist to view GPO reports won't open it (in the XML format).

- Is there a way to convert a GPO report that exists in HTML to XML?
- Are there tools to view GPO reports (HTML or XML) in a more readalbe way?

Danke.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Html is better to view the data.

Comment: TBH I'm not quite sure. I'm trying to learn more about GPOs and the HTML version seems not very easy to read. I thought there might be tools that changes the view to be easier to read.